# search java swing calendar appointement component

Tags: java, swing, javabeans

I am searching for a Java Swing calendar component that would allow adding schedule and reminder features, but [MiG Calendar](http://www.migcalendar.com/) is too expensive. Here's a screenshot:

[image: http://www.migcalendar.com/images/home_screenshot_1.jpg]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

That is a fairly fancy component.  The price is not too bad for what you get.  I don't know of any cheaper or free component that does the exact same thing.  If you put it together yourself you would end up spending more-time an effort than it would cost to just buy this component.

Comment: 755$ and 185$ to have a db connection..... that very bad that there are not really a market for swing component like delphi with vcl....

Comment: rapla is really a nice application, but need no javabean so need to check code and analyze it to be able to get the component